# How to insert all id's from one table to another table

Tags: php

I am trying to get and insert all of the id's from food_variety table into food table. Here is what i am trying to do.

Here i am trying to get all ID's from food_variety table

```
<?php
$Select_Variety = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM food_variety ORDER BY 1 ASC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Select_Variety)){

$variety_ids    = $row['id'];

?>
<div class="list"><?php echo $row['variety_name'];?> <span>$<?php echo $row['price'];?></span>
<input type="text" name="variety_ids2" value="<?php echo $variety_ids;?>">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now here i am trying to insert all ID's from food_variety into food table. But i am unable to do that.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_food'])){

    $food_name      = $_POST['food_name'];
    $description    = $_POST['description'];
    $category       = $_POST['category'];
    $price          = $_POST['price'];
    $tax            = $_POST['tax'];
    $diet_id        = implode(",",$_POST['diet_id']);
    $variety_ids2   = $_POST['variety_ids2'];

$insertQuery = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO food VALUE(
    '',
    '$category',
    '$food_name',
    '$description',
    '$price',
    '$tax',
    '$diet_id',
    '$img',
    '$variety_ids2',
    ''
     )");
```

Database pictures of both tables are attached.  [image]
[image]

Comment: You want to enter all Ids, separating them with commas or, you want to create 3 different rows when data is inserted in the foods table?

Comment: comma separated. i want to enter in 1 column with comma

Comment: Comma separated is not a good design. It makes it much harder to query it or change it later. It should be set up as a proper one-to-many (or many to many?) relationship with separate rows for each entry

Comment: @TeamThunder have you checked what is posted to insert script? I mean the `$_POST['variety_ids2']` is a string or an array?

Comment: i got the issue. I wasn't calling the $variety_ids2 inside a form. I just used this inside a form and it is working now. Just facing the problem now, that it is bringing the last ID, not all ID's. What i can do to bring all ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the variables outside the form. That is why it was inserting the ID values.
Then to take all IDs, I took IDs into an array and then used `implode()` function.

```
<?php
$Show_Variety = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM food_variety ORDER BY 1 ASC");
$ids = [];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Show_Variety)){
$ids[] = $row['id'];
}
?>
<h4>Product Name</h4>
<input type="text" name="variety_id" value="<?php echo implode(", ", $ids); ?>">
```